Textarea - cursor moves to end - react
As I type something in textarea, it works fine. But when I try to take cursor back to add/edit some text, after typing one character it moves to the end.
Code:
React.createElement('textarea', {

                            name: 'SpecialInstruction',
                            id: 'rad_SpecialInstruction', value: this.props.stateobj.SpecialInstruction,
                            onFocus: (event) => {

                                const currentValue = event.target.value;
                                //event.target.value = currentValue + '.';
                                //this.handleOrderChange(event); // trigger the onChange event handler
                            },
                            onChange: this.handleOrderChange, className: 'form-control', maxLength: 512, style: { fontSize: '12px !important' },
                        })
                      )

handleOrderChange code:
_this.handleOrderChange = function (e) {
         

            _this.props.AddModuleState(_defineProperty({}, e.target.name, e.target.value), "RAD");

            // Store the current cursor position
            const cursorPosition = e.target.selectionStart;

            // Prevent the default behavior of the input element
            e.preventDefault();

            _this.props.AddModuleState(_defineProperty({}, e.target.name, e.target.value), "RAD");

           
    

            // Restore the cursor position
            e.target.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);

        };

After I tried fixing this code, I included setTimeout removed e.preventdefault() and removed duplicate AddModuleState line, **It improved a lot but still problem remains! **
My try:
 _this.handleOrderChange = function (e) {
             
  
                _this.props.AddModuleState(_defineProperty({}, e.target.name, e.target.value), "RAD");

                // Store the current cursor position
                const cursorPosition = e.target.selectionStart;
    
               
               setTimeout(() => {
                   e.target.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
               },0);
    
               
            };

Some background that might help:

This is part of application where Drs orders tests for patients.
This textarea's text is meant to remain saved there as we save our order.
We tried removing all the logic in onChange, it worked but text is not saving in text area after we try to edit our orders

